# Print two-column table from Mongo aggregation in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following Mongo aggregation in PHP:

```
    $results = $collection1 -> aggregate (array(

        '$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$Issue',
        'total' => array('$sum' => 1 ), 
        )), array( '$sort' => array( 'total' => -1 ), ));

    print_r($results);
```

It adequately produces the following output:

```
Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [_id] => Sales [total] => 51 ) 
[1] => Array ( [_id] => Service [total] => 41 ) [2] => Array ( [_id] => 
Marketing [total] => 31 ) [3] => Array ( [_id] =>Delivery [total] => 28 )
... etc.
```

Pardon my "noob" question here, but how do I format this into a simple two-column HTML  format showing the name of the category in the first column (e.g., Sales, Marketing, etc.) and the total for each category on the same row?

I don't want to use print_r or var_dump and I've tried various 'foreach' and 'while' methods from this site and am just stumped at this point.

Thank you, kindly, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm maybe I have missed something here but does this do it?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th><th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        foreach($output_var['result'] as $row){
            ?><tr><td><? echo $row['_id']; ?></td><td><? echo $row['total'] ?></td></tr><?
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sammaye, thank you for your time and consideration. With an extra semicolon and a ?>, your code got me the result I was looking for, as follows:

`
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th><th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> <?
        foreach($results['result'] as $row) {
            ?><tr><td><? echo $row['_id']; ?></td><td><? echo $row['total']; ?></td></tr><?
        }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?
`

I'm so new at PHP, I had just timed out after six hours of trying. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Andreas3204 ah yea forgot the php tags so it seems. "just timed out"? You mean the script timed out? It is possible that you are trying to display too many records on the page

Comment: sorry. (I should have been more clear: I, personally, "timed out" after six hours of trying.) Your script worked great and I've adapted it in two other areas, as well. Thanks again for your time and consideration. :)